Exclude data from DTM
I am using ArcGIS 10.8.2 and I would like to estimate the least cost path between points.
I am using a DTM with two lakes and I would exclude these from the least cost path estimation.
I made some proofs generating the slope from the DTM, using the path distance tool with the vertical factor (Tobler’s hiking function) and then using the cost path tool to obtain the network path.
The result took into consideration the lakes passing partially through them.
I would exclude the two water basins from the estimation, thus considering just the territory.

Create a new DTM where the values of the lakes are NoData.  There are several approaches to doing this.  You might try creating polygons for your lakes.  Then convert the lakes to a raster at the same extent of the DTM.  Reclassify such that the lake areas of this new raster are NoData and all other values are 1.  Multiply the reclassified raster with your original DTM.  Since NoData * any value = NoData you should now have a new DTM with NoData values.  Retry your cost path.

Thank you for the answer, but it seems something is wrong. I convert the poly to raster with the extent of the DTM. Then, I reclassify the raster putting “no data” in all field “new values”. The reclassified raster doesn’t appear in the environment. Anyway, I open the raster calculator and multiply the new lake raster and the DTM. The result doesn’t appear in the GIS environment and in the panel the raster shows odd values with minus and plus. Could you help me, please? Thanks

Post another question because GIS SE is not meant to have running dialogs - one question, one answer.  Be sure to include screen shots of your data, your reclassify parameters and anything else that might have clues to your problem.
